# Musixtex Cajon Drum Score

Tags: musixtex, musixper

It is needed to improve the Cajon Drum score for Kids:

1. Add colors for notes and staffs.
2. Configure the Lyrics high and low for easy reading.
3. Improve end bar.

The starting code is as follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{musicography}

\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
%\input {musixps}

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.75\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 

\begin{document}
Cajon percussion for Kids:
\begin{music}
    \resetlyrics
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
    \setlyrics{Vals1}{D {I} D I D D {I} D {I}}%hand indication
    \setlyrics{Vals2}{R {L} R L R R {L} R {L}}%hand indication
    \setsongraise1{-3mm}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\drumclef}%
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}4} %Compás en 3/4
    \setlines{1}{2}
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece% g k
    \A\assignlyrics1{Vals1,Vals2}% added to place handindication
    \Notes\qu k\ibu0h7\qb0{g}\tbu0\qb0{k}\qu k\en\bar%
    \Notes\ibu0k0\qb0{k}\tbu0\qb0{k} \ibu1h7\qb1{g}\tbu1\qb1{k}\ql g\en%
    \Endpiece
\end{music}


\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

Expected output:
[image: expected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using package `xcolor` you'd also use command `\textcolor`, using either the standard colors defined or defining as needed.

As a test I defined a newcommand `\pnk{}`, and used it both for text and notes. As you can see, there is some interaction with the lyrics package. You'll probably do better when typesetting note by note, i.e. these 2 voices notewise. I'd replace the lyrics by two newcommands, which place text where needed, using zchar and similar.

Using these approaches you should be able to resolve your 1st and 2nd part of this question.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{musicography}

\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
%\input {musixps}

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.75\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 

% new
\newcommand\pnk[1]{\textcolor{magenta}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\pnk{Cajon percussion for Kids:}% just a test

\vspace{10pt}
\begin{music}
    \resetlyrics
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
    \setlyrics{Vals1}{D {I} D I D D {I} D {I}}%hand indication
    \setlyrics{Vals2}{R {L} R L R R {L} R {L}}%hand indication
    \setsongraise1{-3mm}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\drumclef}%
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}4} %Compás en 3/4
    \setlines{1}{2}
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece% g k
    \A\assignlyrics1{Vals1,Vals2}% added to place handindication
    \Notes\pnk{\qu k}\ibu0h7\qb0{g}\tbu0\pnk{\qb0{k}}\qu k\en\bar%
    \Notes\ibu0k0\qb0{k}\tbu0\qb0{k} \ibu1h7\qb1{g}\tbu1\qb1{k}\ql g\en%
    \Endpiece
\end{music}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, colors work with boxes, which makes use with other horizontal spacing tricky. What I did, is define the necessary `\zcharnotes` and not working with lyrics this time. It seems a bit laborious,but seems to work. The ending line disappears after musixflx procedure. I looked at your expected output. Therefore I separated the notes by using `\cl`. Due to the use of boxes, you have to skip backwards in the second bar, and then forwards again after having placed the second D. Maybe there is a way to eliminate the expand after a color box, but I am not familiar with such programming. I am a user of MusixTex …[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{musicography}

\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
%\input {musixps}

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.75\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 

% new
\newcommand\pnk[1]{\textcolor{magenta}{#1}}%
\newcommand\grn[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}%
\begin{document}
\pnk{Cajon percussion for Kids:}% just a test

\begin{music}
    \resetlyrics
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
    \def\Dp{\zcharnote s{\A\pnk{D}}}%
        \def\Ip{\zcharnote s{\A\pnk{I}}}%
    \def\Ig{\zcharnote I{\A\grn{I}}}%
      \def\Dg{\zcharnote I{\A\grn{D}}}%        
        \def\Lg{\zcharnote C{\A\grn{L}}}% 
        \def\Rg{\zcharnote C{\A\grn{R}}}%   
        \def\Lp{\zcharnote C{\A\pnk{L}}}% 
        \def\Rp{\zcharnote C{\A\pnk{R}}}%         
    \instrumentnumber{1}%
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\drumclef}%
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}4} %Compás en 3/4
    \setlines{1}{2}%
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece% g k
    \Notes\Dp\Rp\pnk{\qu k}\Lg\Ig\grn{\cl g}\Rp\Dp\pnk{\cu k}\Lp\Ip\pnk{\qu k}\en\bar%
    \Notes\Dp\Rp\pnk{\ibu0k0\qb0k\tbu0\qb0k}\bsk\Dp\Rp\sk\Ig\Lg\grn{\cl g}\Dp\Rp\pnk{\cu k}\Ig\Lg\grn{\ql g}\en%
    \Endpiece
\end{music}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Well done. Thanks for re-using my partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

When use the \textcolor, the lyrics gets a shift right as show in the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{musicography}

\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
%\input {musixps}

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.75\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 

% new
\newcommand\pnk[1]{\textcolor{magenta}{#1}}
\newcommand\grn[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\pnk{Cajon percussion for Kids:}% just a test

\begin{music}
    \resetlyrics
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
    \setlyrics{Vals1}{D I D I D D I D I}%hand indication
    \setlyrics{Vals2}{R L R L R R L R L}%hand indication
    \setsongraise1{-3mm}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\drumclef}%
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}4} %Compás en 3/4
    \setlines{1}{2}
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%
    \startpiece% g k
    \A\assignlyrics1{Vals1,Vals2}% added to place handindication
    %\Notes\qu k\ibu0h7\qb0{g}\tbu0\qb0{k}\qu k\en\bar%
    %\Notes\ibu0k0\qb0{k}\tbu0\qb0{k} \ibu1h7\qb1{g}\tbu1\qb1{k}\ql g\en%
    \Notes\pnk{\qu k}\grn{\ibu0h7\qb0{g}\tbu0\pnk{\qb0{k}}}\pnk{\qu k}\en\bar%
    \Notes\hsk\pnk{\ibu0k0\qb0{k}\tbu0\qb0{k}} \grn{\ibu1h7\qb1{g}\tbu1\pnk{\qb1{k}}}\grn{\ql g}\en%
    \Endpiece
\end{music}


\end{document}
```

The output is as follow:
[image: output]